# How to create wallets without a full node (cardano light client)

Tags: cardano-cli, wallet, lightwallet

The only useful resource I could find is the .NET package [cardanosharp-wallet](https://github.com/CardanoSharp/cardanosharp-wallet) which is not ideal since I don't know .NET.

Are there alternatives in other languages, for local wallet generation (also supporting sub-accounts)?

I found multiple REST APIs that I can use to interact with the chain without having a full node locally (for faster developing & testing), but what I miss is the starting point: being able to create wallets!

As for the official docs, both [cardanocli-js](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/cardanocli-js) and [cardano-wallet-js](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/cardano-wallet-js) depend on cardano-node, either directly or through cardano-wallet

I don't understand the full node requirement since I can prompt txs from my (off-chain) app-created accounts to the browser wallets using the [common API](https://www.cardano-caniuse.io/). Is it needed to generate the CBOR even for simple send/stake transactions?
What would be the minimal tools needed that are part of cardano-wallet package?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are familiar with JS/TS so I suggest you use https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-js-sdk with a blockchain query provider such as Blockfrost. This is the sdk used by Lace wallet so you should have everything you need.